# How to show a date format in Jquery ui datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I select jquery ui datepicker. It does not show the datepicker. It shows like November/Wednesday/YYYY h:11 A. but I want ex : 11/17/2016 5:51 PM. please help me with it.

```
 $('#start-date').datetimepicker({
    addSliderAccess: true,
    sliderAccessArgs: {touchonly: false},
    timeFormat: "h:mm TT",
    minDate: 0, 
    dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A',
    onSelect: function(date) {
        console.log('date :' + date);
        console.log('id :' + this.id);

        if (this.id == "start-date") {
            var endDate_picker = $("#end-date");
            var minDate = moment(date,"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
            var endDate = moment(moment(minDate).toDate()).add('hours', 2);
            if ((endDate_picker.val() == "")||
                    (moment(endDate_picker.val(),"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A").toDate()) < minDate.toDate()) {
                $(endDate_picker).datetimepicker("setDate", endDate.toDate());

                console.log('set date :' + endDate.toDate());
            }
            $(endDate_picker).datetimepicker("option", "minDate", minDate.toDate());
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A',` with your desired format.

Please, check [this link](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) to see which options you can set for the DATE, and [this one](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) for the TIME (*Formatting* tab)

To get 11/17/2016 5:51 PM, if you're using bootstrap datetimepicker, you should use something like this:

```
format: 'm/d/Y h:i A',
```

If you tell us which library are you using for the datetimepicker we can help you better.

**EDIT:** Please check **[this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kamae/ehk73jr4/)** I did for you. (Using **Bootstrap DateTimePicker**)

Comment: I changed it.  i am getting only date 11/17/2016. but i am not getting time and PM or AM? please help me.

Comment: I've eddited my post, try that please

Comment: Deprecation warning: moment().add(period, number) is deprecated. Please use moment().add(number, period).

Comment: i am getting above warning in browser console.

Comment: Can you tell me which library are you using? It is the Bootstrap datetimepicker?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: <script src='<c:url value = "/resources/js/moment.min.js"/>'></script>

Comment: OK I tried this with bootstrap datetimepicker(): format: 'm/d/Y h:i A'

Comment: hello man , thanks for effort.   and  how to set one picker date to another date picker ? ex: start-date and end-date

Comment: You're setting that datepicker only to  $('#start-date') (that means your element with id="start-date"). Just add a comma and another one, or use a common class - e.g. ".isDatepicker".

So you can use $('#start-date, #end-date').datetimepicker(...) but then remember to modify in onSelect function this block: if (this.id == "start-date") { ... } to add a: else if (this.id == "end-date") { ... }